# Error NoSuchMethodError en el constructor con int

Tags: java

Tengo este programa:

```
package prueba;

import clases.Persona;


public class Descuentos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persona p = new Persona();
    p.setEdad(20);






}

}
```

y esta clase:

```
package clases;

public class Persona {
 String nombre;
 int numero;
 int edad;
 double salario;

public Persona(int numero){
    this.numero = numero;
}

public Persona() {


}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

public void setSalario(double salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}
```

}
Cuando lo inializo me sale esta excepción:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clases.Persona.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

¿Sabeis cual es el motivo?

Comment: Entiendo que has revisado que los 'imports' de las clases estén bien no?

Comment: si esta comprobado

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el código que tienes? no debería de haber ningún error, según lo que has puesto, a no ser que los tengas en paquetes distintos o algo?

Comment: si los tengo en paquetes distintos pero los tengo importados

Comment: Acabo de probar tu ejemplo y no me ha dado ningún error.

Comment: Pues no se la verdad, si pruebo con un contructor vacio funciona bien pero si ya pongo un setNumero me vuelve a dar error...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código tal y como lo tienes en la clase persona? incluyendo el Package y los import?

Comment: No veo ningún método llamado `setNumero()` en el código que has pasado.

Comment: ya esta actualizado

Comment: No debería haber ningún error @bsg ¿Tienes las clases actualizadas? prueba a guardarlas y demás...

Comment: si, no se que pasa

Comment: Acabo de probar tu clase tal y como la tienes en la pregunta y no me ocurre ningún error

Comment: Que IDE de programación estas utilizando? si es Netbeans y en vista de que no me ha dado ningún error al probar el código, te recomendaría dar click derecho sobre tu proyecto y dar click en la opción "Clean" quizás de esta forma lo soluciones.

Comment: lo solucioné, era una clase que se llamaba igual y la tenía en librerias.Muchas gracias